# Retag request: 10.4 instead of 10.04

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

Would someone please retag [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2258/keyboard-mouse-not-recognised-during-installation) with 10.04 instead of 10.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Happy to do so. Edited the instance in the question too.

Comment: Missed the instance in the second paragraph as of the time of this writing, that needs to be changed too.

Comment: @jdk - Good call.